# Stata drop observations command

Tags: stata

I have panel data for two years for individuals (id). A dummy variable (empl) takes on three values (1,2,3). I'd like to keep only those ids which take on a value of 1. What Stata command should I use?

Comment: What code did you try? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask a good question. "take on a value of 1": ever (at least once) or always (for every observation in a panel)?

Comment: I think the bulk of the answer is in your question (`help drop`). However, without further details as to your data structure, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @NickCox I'd like to keep only those ids for which empl  is always 1 and get rid of those ids for which empl equals to 0, 2 or 3. I tried this code -  by empl , sort: keep if empl==1  but it did not delete enough observation.

Answer (score 0):

The code cited in the comments

```
by empl, sort: keep if empl == 1
```

is equivalent to

```
keep if empl == 1
```

and pays no attention to the panel structure.

What is wanted is to keep panels for which `empl` is always 1: if that is so, the minimum and maximum are always 1, so a criterion is

```
by id (empl), sort: keep if empl[1] == empl[_N] & empl[1] == 1
```

or

```
by id (empl), sort: keep if empl[1] == 1 & empl[_N] == 1
```